# QR Code Checkin extension use with recurring events

Tags: civievent

Is there a way to use the same QR code to record a student's attendance to all the sessions/classes of a course? Or does the [extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/qr-code-checkin) require generating a different QR code for each session?